# Align bitmap in SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: android, spannablestring

How can I align a bitmap to the text in a SpannableString?

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(arr_messages.get(position));
String msg1 = ssb.toString();
for (int i=0; i<smileys.length; i++)
{   
        if (msg1.indexOf(smileys[i]) > 0)
        {
            int t = msg1.indexOf(smileys[i]);
            ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bitmapArray.get(i)), t, t+2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
}
holder.txtName.setText(ssb, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

I would like to demonstrate the problem with these images:

What I want is to center both the text and the image vertically (the text is ok, but the image screws it up).

The result is:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `...new ImageSpan(bitmapArray.get(i), ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE)...`!