# Vertically align images defined by HTML in TextView

Tags: android, html, image, textview

I have a `TextView` containing text and image(s) in html, i.e. `"some text with <img src=\"hello\"/> image"`.
To display images properly the `Html.ImageGetter` is used, which reads the requested drawable from resources and sets its bounds according on the `TextView`'s height.
Currently it looks like the images are aligned to the baseline of the `TextView`, while I would like them to appear vertically centered. Is it possible and how?

Comment: See this question, it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751195/align-bitmap-in-spannablestringbuilder

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet will help you.

```
private class ImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter {
public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
    BitmapDrawable d = getPicture(source);
    d.setBounds(new Rect(0,0,d.getIntrinsicWidth(),d.getIntrinsicHeight()+5));
    d.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    return d;
  } 
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to set center the android:gravity or the android:layout_gravity?

Comment: Yes, I tried the `android:gravity` parameter with `center_vertical` and `top` and it didn't help.

Comment: Maybe you have to search for some html tags

Comment: If you put html code inside your TextView to show an imagine, maybe you can also format it by html code

Comment: I have not found such a functionality in HTML tags and attributes available in TextView...