# How quotes align-top with text in TextView?

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring, spannablestringbuilder

I have a spannnable string and that spannable sting containg images
and string and but When i Display that string on textview that images
align with base line of textview i want to display ALIGN_TOP with that
string I am stuck on this please help me to sort out.

Here is my code

```
        String text2 = "  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing   and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.  ";

        Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(text2);

        spannable.setSpan(new ImageSpan(mActivity, R.mipmap.start_quote_green), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        spannable.setSpan(new ImageSpan(mActivity, R.mipmap.end_quote_green), text2.length()-1, text2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

        inspirationalActivityInspirationalTextTv.setText(spannable, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Output
[image: result]

Required
[image: required]

Comment: Hint: you are misusing the `mipmap` folder/s. That folder must contain **only the launcher icon**. And **nothing else** (i.e.: NOT the app graphical resources). Those ones must be put in the `drawable` folder/s.

Comment: @ModularSynth we can use mipmap folder for graphical rsource its not and issue for app

Comment: It's not an issue, right. But it's also not correct: [the res/mipmap folder for a launcher icon, or the res/drawable folder for other types of icons.](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically align images defined by HTML in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428126/vertically-align-images-defined-by-html-in-textview). You have to search, before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is Answer**

```
        String text2 = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.   ";

        Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(text2);
        spannable.setSpan(new TopImageSpan(mActivity, R.mipmap.start_quote_green), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        spannable.setSpan(new TopImageSpan(mActivity, R.mipmap.end_quote_green), text2.length()-1, text2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);


        inspirationalActivityInspirationalTextTv.setText(spannable, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

**TopImageSpan Class For Align Top with text**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.text.style.DynamicDrawableSpan;
import android.text.style.ImageSpan;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

/**
 * Created by Humayoon on 8/10/17.
 */

public class TopImageSpan extends ImageSpan {

    private WeakReference<Drawable> mDrawableRef;
    public static boolean startQuote = false,EndQuote = true;

    public TopImageSpan(Context context, final int drawableRes) {
        super(context, drawableRes);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text,
                       int start, int end,
                       Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
        Drawable d = getCachedDrawable();
        Rect rect = d.getBounds();

        if (fm != null) {
            Paint.FontMetricsInt pfm = paint.getFontMetricsInt();
            // keep it the same as paint's fm
            fm.ascent = pfm.ascent;
            fm.descent = pfm.descent;
            fm.top = pfm.top;
            fm.bottom = pfm.bottom;
        }

        return rect.right;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas, CharSequence text,
                     int start, int end, float x,
                     int top, int y, int bottom, @NonNull Paint paint) {
        Drawable b = getCachedDrawable();
        canvas.save();

        int drawableHeight = b.getIntrinsicHeight();
        int fontAscent = paint.getFontMetricsInt().ascent;
        int fontDescent = paint.getFontMetricsInt().descent;
        int transY = bottom - b.getBounds().bottom +  // align bottom to bottom
                (drawableHeight - fontDescent + fontAscent);  // align center to center

        canvas.translate(x, transY);
        b.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    // Redefined locally because it is a private member from DynamicDrawableSpan
    private Drawable getCachedDrawable() {
        WeakReference<Drawable> wr = mDrawableRef;
        Drawable d = null;

        if (wr != null)
            d = wr.get();

        if (d == null) {
            d = getDrawable();
            mDrawableRef = new WeakReference<>(d);
        }

        return d;
    }
}
```